# C++ - For loop not working

Tags: c++, for-loop

My for loop (for debugging) for a capitalism simulator I'm making is not working, as it is exiting at ix=0 (it only executes the loop body once).
I also believe it is syntactially correct (from other questions).

Here is my code (I left out the variables):

```
void print_things(String2Double b, String2Double up_cost, String2Double tFinish, string* bNames) {
    // Just for debugging!
    for (int ix=0;ix<(sizeof(bNames)/sizeof(bNames[0]));ix++) {
        cout << "Count of business " << bNames[ix] << ": " << b[bNames[ix]] << endl;
        cout << "Upgrade cost for " << bNames[ix] << ": " << up_cost[bNames[ix]] << endl;
        cout << "Time to finish for " << bNames[ix] << ": " << tFinish[bNames[ix]] << endl;
        cout << ix << endl;
    }
}
```

I also had it print the size of `bNames[]`, which is 9 and it only printed ix=0,
and I suspected something must be wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the club of C/C++ most frequently asked questions.

Comment: Why not replace `(sizeof(bNames)/sizeof(bNames[0]))` with `9`?

Comment: Since none of the answers below have mentioned it, the phenomenon is known as "**array decaying to pointer**". You might want to look it up on your favorite search engine (Yahoo, DuckDuckGo, StartPage, IxQuick, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here `bNames` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: But if I use string instead of string* in the declaration, it raises an error that it cannot convert from string* to string.

Comment: pass the length of array as an extra parameter.

Comment: I can't do that because I have an array of variable length.

Comment: So you want me to pass in `sizeof bNames/sizeof bNames[0]` as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
(sizeof(bNames)/sizeof(bNames[0]))
```

is not working as you think it should.

That part probably was copied by you without understanding because it's only valid for an array, not for a pointer. Also declaring the parameter as `bNames[]` in the function wouldn't work either.

You need to pass explicitly the number of elements when using a pointer.

A better approach in C++ would be using an `std::vector` (but it's strongly suggested you first understand how it works).

## Edit

You can only pass **array references** (not arrays) in C++ if you know the size at compile time, using as syntax:

```
void print_i10(int (&a)[10]) {
    // `a` here is a reference to an array of 10 integers
}
```

It's also possible to pass arrays to **function templates**, having the template infer the array size at compile time; for example:

```
template<typename T, int N>
void print(const char *format, const T (&a)[N]) {
    printf("[");
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        if (i) printf(", ");
        printf(format, a[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int ia[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    const char *sa[] = {"this", "that", "hmmm..."};

    print("%i", ia);
    print("'%s'", sa);

    return 0;
}
```

but this means that for each element type and element size you will get a distinct copy of the `print` function in your program (normally a bad idea).

Comment: I _am_ passing in an **array**, and I used that to print out the size. Also the array _is_ not a pointer, it just has unspecified length.

Comment: You cannot pass an array to a regular function in C/C++. When passing an array the argument decays into a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Then how _do_ I prevent array decay? I've searched it up but there is no straightforward solution.

Comment: You really cannot prevent it.  If you're using C++ you should learn to use containers like `std::vector` that allow you to query their size, not raw pointers.

Comment: @AnirudhBalaji: see edit for some more of the truth about array parameters in C++. Until you get enough understanding of C++ however it's much better to just use `std::vector` instead (and once you'll have enough understanding you'll see that using `std::vector` is better 99% of the times).